# svg shape that grow based on the text in it?

Tags: xml, svg, xhtml

I was trying to come up with a SVG that can dynamically fits the size of the text. here is what I came up so far:

```html
 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
   style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px black;"
>
  <title>simulated wrapping in svg</title>
  <desc>A foreignObject container</desc>

   <!-- Text-Elemente -->
   <foreignObject
      x="100" y="100" width="200" height="150"
      transform="translate(0,0)"
   >
      <xhtml:div style="padding:10px; color:black; text-align:center; background-color: red;">Demo test dasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas is supposed to be asdqe arasd qweewsdord-wrappsdaed sdasdadomewhere along the line to show that it is indeed possible to simulate ordinary text containers in svg.dsadasds</xhtml:div>
      
      
   </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

This is a good start the main issue here is that I need to know before the size (HxW) I would use in the shape. I could somehow calculate it based on the characters. But I just wanted to know if there is a easy/ier way to achieve this?
As you can see n the example the text overflows the box and if I put a shorter text the box will have this gap below.